# How to send bulk email using smtp avoiding spam

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail, html-email

I have a website and I need to send newsletters for subscribers around 2k. But the email sent to subscribers in spam. How to overcome this problem? Please suggest smtp configuration to avoid spam in-case of any.

I am sending

1) HTML TEXT
2) I use c# code to send the mail
3) Am giving some email address with my domain name. For e.g : Newsletter@mydomain.com as FROM ADDRESS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First do a test send to a service like http://www.isnotspam.com/

From there you can diagnose your issue. Check the report lines with "1.0" or "-0.5" because those are issues that affect your overall score (>10.0 = spam). It may just be an issue with your HTML, or how you're setting up your MIME header.

Answer (score 0):

You should check these checklist and search each one to pass.

1. **SPF**
2. **DKIM**
3. **DMARC**

Also, It should be great to set **reverse domain name** "mydomain.com".

First, let's see how to check these 4 items to find out which one is incorrect.

To check SPF, DKIM and DMARC, you should send a test email to your Gmail then go to Gmail inbox and check "Original Message" of the email. This image is an example:
[image]
To check reverse domain name search it. there are tools to check it.

Please search spf, dmarce and domainkey and also read my note.

**What is spf:** You can set it in DNS zone. with this you are limiting the Valid IP address that could send email with your domain name. for example when gmail receive an email from YourDomainName.com it can read the domain DNS and check the SPF to see is this ip address valid or not.

**What is dmarc:** You can set it in DNS zone. You are introducing an email address to receivers (gmail, yahoo, live and ...) to send their report to that.

**What is domainkey:** First let's see what is it. We should use a encryption method such sha256 to authenticate email. In every encryption method you have a private_key and a public_key. You should configure your mail server to put private_key in email and introduce the public_key as _domainkey in DNS zone.

Finally you can sign in to gmail postmaster to see reports about emails that gmail is receiving from your domain.
Take a look
[image]

**Bulk email:**
To send bulk email you should set header in c#:

```
mailtest.Headers.Add("Precedence", "bulk");
```

Read also documents about sending bulk email from [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en&ref_topic=7279058) and yahoo. They talk about many aspect of sending bulk email for example you should begin sending email by 100 emails per day and after a while you can increase it to 1000 emails per day.